# Блок overflow auto внутри flex перестаёт расширяться в firefox, скролл перекрывает контент

Tags: javascript, html, css

Иногда при вёрстке блоков с `overflow: auto` в firefox блок становится не жадным по ширине и при появлении вертикальной полосы прокрутки создаётся горизонтальная, так как вертикальная отбирает место. В хроме такой проблемы нет.

Временно использую js и вставляю `margin-right` с вычисленным размером скролла (обычно 17px)

Это можно как-нибудь фиксить без js? Может быть какая-то известная ошибка вёрстки. Если нельзя исправить это вёрсткой, то возможно для этого есть готовый общеизвестный скрипт (как например clearfix в css).

Запретить горизонтальный скролл - не выход, потому что проблема не в наличии скролла, а в отсутствии жадности ширины у блока. К тому же горизонтальный скролл может потребоваться по прямому назначению, если у блока не останется места для расширения

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/etsw8nuh/

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="wrap2">
       <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.block {
  position: relative;
}
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
/* Code below fixes trouble when scroll size is 17px */
/* .wrap2 {
  margin-right: 17px;
} */
.item {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: blue;
}
```

[image]

## UPD

Кажется это баг https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1474932 ([демо](https://codepen.io/PavelKunof/pen/gjbopP))
Если это до сих пор невозможно исправить стилями, то возможно есть известные js патчи, если это так, сошлитесь на такой патч.

Comment: добавил к .wrap{ display:flex } и заработало))

Comment: @grime куда добавил? Покажи пример. У меня это ничего не меняет

Comment: https://fastpic.ru/fullview/111/2020/0204/675564a553a05fc049c31fc1b4c8df3a.jpg.html

Comment: @grime понял. Проблема не в этом. Я хочу что бы блок расширялся пока есть свободное пространство. Этот блок не расширяется при любом количестве свободного пространства

Comment: overflow-y: scroll вместо overflow: auto?

Comment: @grime это работает, но тогда скролл отображается всегда. Обрати внимание как это работает в хроме, при появлении контента появляется вертикальный скролл и ширина wrap увеличивается. Это моя цель

Answer (score 0):

Дефолтная ширина у .wrap выставляется разная, т.к. этот блок имеет абсолютное позиционирование. Для того чтобы исправить проблему необходимо выставить .wrap 100% ширину, и если необходимо ограничить этот блок по ширине использовать max-width

```html
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%; /*добавлено*/
  max-width: 400px; /*добавлено*/
}
```

Comment: Блок будет расширяться только до размера родителя с `position: relative`. Это ограничивает размер блока, вместо решения проблемы появления скролла из-за нежелания блока расширяться. Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/r2nvksoa/2/

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло навесить на контент, у которого скролл, свойства:

```
z-index: 1
position: relative
```

Comment: У этого блока свойство `position` должно быть `absolute`. В этом смысл задачи